# Oracle Apex apex_application.g_f10.COUNT is 0

Tags: oracle, checkbox, oracle-apex

Oracle Apex: 5

This appears to be simple however I'm unable to get through this.

I'm testing the `apex_application.g_f10.COUNT` by inserting the checked value in a dummy table following is the code I'm using:

```
declare
begin
:P20_LIST:=APEX_APPLICATION.G_F10.COUNT;
    FOR i in 1 .. apex_application.g_f10.COUNT
        LOOP
            insert into test values (apex_application.g_f10(i) );
            insert into test values (2045);
            commit;
        end loop;
 end;
```

The process is not entering the loop even though values are checked on the following IR and `:P20_LIST` is 0:

```
 select INVENTORY_ITEM_ID,
 apex_item.checkbox(10,INVENTORY_ITEM_ID) selected,
  NAME,QUANTITY,SERIAL_NUMBER,IIL_NAME from inventory_items@NAM;
```

Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: Did you submit the page? Here's a reference https://storm-petrel.com/orablog/2016/01/02/apex_item-check_box2/

Answer (score 0):

When ever we use check box as report column in report we have to make sure that column attribute should be ***Standard report column*** .Then only it will written the value

[image]